# Is there a better way to implement range based if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'be recently had a project in which I had to change some value based on a range of some other value...

so the code is pretty much like this:

```
let color = "black"
const temp = await api.get('/temperature') //fake call
if (temp <= 10) {
  color = 'blue'
} else if (temp > 10 && temp >= 20) {
  color = 'green';
} else if (temp > 20 && temp <= 30) {
  color = 'yellow';
} else if (temp > 30) {
  color = 'red'
}
```

is there any way to make this condition more "clean"?

Comment: `color = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red"][Math.floor((temp + 1)/ 10)];` (although you might want to clamp `temp` to valid values before using that - there's also a type in your code , `>= 20`)

Comment: Nothing 'unclean' about this... either this or a `switch` statement should you aim for something maintainable.

Comment: @ChrisG Fits for this scenario, fails if `temp > 25 && temp < 29`

Comment: You can remove the first condition for "green" and "yellow". And I guess it should be `temp <= 20` instead of `>=`.

Comment: @Justinas Thanks, fixed (`ceil` was meant to address `<=` but I should've checked :)

Comment: Yes I'm aware we can use switch case, i was wondering if there is a way to implement this in a way that i won't be  needed to write 100 if else / case statements...

Comment: Your code, shortended: `if (temp <= 10) color = 'blue';
else if (temp <= 20) color = 'green';
else if (temp <= 30) color = 'yellow';
else color = 'red';` (and leave it to me to put a typo in "typo" ;))